# Image doesn't show after editing template meteor.js

Tags: javascript, html, templates, meteor

[Screenshot of the web app on command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K55UD.png)
[Screenshot of the project folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24NC2.png)

I've tried editing a template in meteor.js but when I put the image file in the template, the image is not shown on the web browser
    
      image_share

```
<body>
  <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>

  {{> images}}
</body>

<template name="images">
    <img src="public/Aliens.jpg" alt="Aliens!">
</template>
```

image_share is the folder which has a css file, a js file and an html file. I have created a folder public in image_share and put the image Aliens.jpg in it. When i run this on the browser, it just shows :
"Welcome to Meteor!
 {{> images}}"
The image is not shown. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Try using an absolute path, perhaps `/public/Aliens.jpg`?

Comment: just `<img src="/Aliens.jpg" alt="Aliens!">` should do it.

Comment: @PedroLobito thats not working!

Comment: @m0atz  I tried what you suggested, but it still does not display the image.

Comment: try just `<img src="Aliens.jpg" alt="Aliens!">` I replicated your file setup and this works. If it fails your end, there must be something else in your code / setup.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `/public` - that directory maps to `/`

Comment: I have tried that as well. But it still doesn't show my image.

Answer (score 0):

By default metoer understands that you assets like images, documents and other attachment files will be based at location of Project/public/, So you just need to specify the file name or the path from folder inside public directory. That's it bro.

Below is examle,

1. **For public/sample.jpg => path is 'sample.jpg'**
2. **For public/IMG/sample.JPG => path is 'IMG/sample.JPG'**

Comment: I have tried that earlier, in fact that was what i started with but as it wasnt showing the image then, I thought I would have to add public/ too. In either case, the image is not being displayed.

Comment: The public folder has to be created in the project folder. BTW can you paste the code snippet here, as to let us know what is wrong. Also put a snapshot of your folder structure.

Comment: I just tried something and didn't understand. I ran the web application from my command prompt, copied the URL it showed at the end to chrome and there the image was there. Then again I went to Brackets (my text editor) and ran the above code. When run via brackets, the image wasn't shown. And yes, I have the public folder in the project folder. As I am getting the correct output from command prompt URL, there shouldn't be a problem with the folders as such.

Comment: No, the URL in command prompt when pasted in chrome gives the image. But when run from my text editor, it doesn't. I think the image should also be shown when run from the text editor. In text editor case, it just shows {{> images}} instead of the image.

Comment: i can help only if i see what you have done. my skype @ankursoni697

Comment: I've added the link to the command prompt and project folder screenshots.